# running image_view with pointgrey flea3 camera

Tags: stereo-calibration, viso2-ros, image, libviso2, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I installed the driver for two Flea3 Pointgrey cameras whose accessibility are (successfully) verified via:

> rosrun pointgrey_camera_driver list_cameras

12062824
12062828

Now "starting" one of those cameras with

> roslaunch pointgrey_camera_driver camera.launch camera_serial:=12062824

I would like to display my images with

> rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image

but I receive the following error code:

> [ERROR] [1404221648.972130708]: Client
> [/image_view_1404220593387350082]
> wants topic /camera/image to have
> datatype/md5sum
> [sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743],
> but our version has
> [wfov_camera_msgs/WFOVImage/807d0db423ab5e1561cfeba09a10bc88].
> Dropping connection. [ERROR]
> [1404221696.898906591]: Client
> [/image_view_1404221696410391988]
> wants topic /camera/image to have
> datatype/md5sum
> [sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743],
> but our version has
> [wfov_camera_msgs/WFOVImage/807d0db423ab5e1561cfeba09a10bc88].
> Dropping connection.

It seems like the camera.launch script publishes the images in a message format which is not known to
image_view.

As I am a beginner to Linux as well as ROS I would like to ask for some tips how to publish
my images (or edit camera.launch) in a certain way, eg. under the topic "left_camera/image".

Also how would I take a first step in displaying my images from the camera?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/181679/running-image_view-with-pointgrey-flea3-camera/) by [mister_kay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18994/mister_kay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asdfgf](https://answers.ros.org/users/26977/asdfgf/) on 2016-06-28**:
Can I Know how did you resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you go to run `image_view`, you have to view the "raw" image format using `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw`.

Let me know if this works and if you are able to view both at once. I'm having issues attempting to view both streams simultaneously at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [JustBenj](https://answers.ros.org/users/26066/justbenj/) with karma: 16 on 2016-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam6](https://answers.ros.org/users/31098/sam6/) on 2017-08-24**:
Hi, when I run the above command, a blank window opens up. I am able to get some data when I run 'rostopic echo /camera/image' but not able to view it using image_view. What could it be that am doing wrong?